# Get textbox with values and Checked Checkboxes from formcollection MVC 4

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

I am new to MVC and feeling blindfolded. May be silly.

I have form with 20 textboxes , checkboxes and few dropdowns. I want to get checked checkboxes, textbox with values and dropdowns that has selected values from formcollection. I dont know where to start. I only have a httppost action method..

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult virusLookup(FormCollection collection)
   {

     return RedirectToAction("getVirusDetails");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.108).aspx) method. It has many overloads so you can eg. specify which field do you want include or exclude. You can also just replace FormCollection with your specified class and then ASP.NET MVC bind properties automatically.

```
if (this.TryUpdateModel(model, collection)) 
{
    // do some logic with your model
}
```

Comment: I still cant figure out things. Why would i update my model ? I want to fetch textboxes with values and checked chkboxes. its a search criteria. I need them to create sql query. I dont have to update my model !

Comment: Don't treat model as something that you store in database. In your case create model called eg. `CustomerCriteria` and use that model to create your sql query.

Comment: oh !? okay then. Now = I am reading all overloads of TryupdatePanel.  now:after { model to sql ! }  thanks for the tip.